# Missing DLL (d3dx11d_43.dll) while debugging DirectX 11 program

Tags: c++, dll, directx

I've just started DirectX development, and I'm simply trying to initialize the program and render a blue screen. The program compiles, but immediately gives me the error "The program can't start because d3dx11d_43.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

I've installed and reinstalled the DirectX June 2010 SDK, and I've found 2 instances of a DLL by that name inside the installation folder, but my program can't seem to find it.

I'm running VS 2012 Ultimate on 64-bit Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

D3DX is not part of the standard DirectX installation. If you rely on D3DX then you must install it separately on each machine that runs your program. The DirectX SDK includes redistributable packages for D3DX. That's something that you will need to address if ever you redistribute your program.

In the meantime, your program appears to be linking to the debug version of D3DX. I'm not sure if that is intentional on your part. You could probably get your program to run simply by copying `d3dx11d_43.dll` into the directory that contains your executable. That would probably suffice for debugging purposes. If you don't need to debug the DLL itself, and I doubt that you do, then using the release version of the D3DX .lib file will link against the release DLL which I expect is already installed in your system directory.